# pyzmq - undefined symbol: zmq_msg_gets

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I have problem with zeromq, I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):   File "BasicPub.py", line 1, in <module>
    import zmq   File "/home/przemek/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from zmq import backend   File "/home/przemek/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)   File "/home/przemek/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)   File "/home/przemek/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 27, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)   File "/home/przemek/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context, ImportError: /home/przemek/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/message.so: undefined symbol: zmq_msg_gets
```

I installed it this way:

```
tar xzvf zeromq-4.1.4.tar.gz 
./configure
./configure --without-libsodium
make
sudo make install
pip install pyzmq
```

I use python2.7 and Ubuntu 14.04

Could you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use pip for installing pyzmq, I'd suggest to try installing zmq bundled to pyzmq:

```
  pip install pyzmq --install-option="--zmq=bundled"
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the error I was having when trying to use Jupyter 4.4.0 and Python 2.7.12.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that zeromq 4.0.4 (ubuntu / trusty version) does not have function `zmq_msg_gets` and zeromq 4.1.4 has that function, suggests that wrong version of C library is being used.

New version of the C library was probably found when pyzmq was built, but for some reason old version is loaded when the module is loaded.